# unable to cast an object returnd from outside of my app

Tags: c#, casting, .net-assembly

I have retrycode Logic outside of my application which Loads the Assemblies using `Assembly.LoadFile(Asmpath);`
and returns the object from the loaded assembly back to the my application.

and i have the reference to the same assembly in app. which i have created using Add Refferences.

i am able to return the object. but while casting the returned object to its type in my application its throwing the following Error:

> [A]SampleAssembly1.Class1 cannot be cast to [B]SampleAssembly1.Class1. Type A originates from 'SampleAssembly1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\Users\v-saabdu\Desktop\Final Code for RetryMethod\ReflectionSamples\SampleAssembly1\bin\Debug\SampleAssembly1.dll'. Type B originates from 'SampleAssembly1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Users\v-saabdu\Desktop\Final Code for RetryMethod\ReflectionSamples\ReflectionAssembly\bin\Debug\SampleAssembly1.dll'.

from the above error message I understood that the way assemblies are loaded in my application and in retrycode (outside of my app) differning in context.

can any one suggest me solution for this..

Thankx,

Comment: how you are loading the assembly, because its not included her, and do both classes implemented common interface to be able to cast them

Comment: I am having the same problem in .net 7, did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("Libtest.dll");
TestLib lib = (TestLib)assembly.CreateInstance("Lib");
lib.doSomething();
```

Lib class must implement the TestLib interface and must be accessible both from both Foo.dll and bar.dll.

Comment: no dude the type for these instance are also same ,. but the way they are loaded is different.. one is loaded using Assmly.LoadFile() and another is using Add Referrence. when we load an Assemly using Assembly.LoadFile it will load assembly in Loadneither Context and when we load assembly by adding referrence it will load Assembly in Defaul Context. so here the problem is unmatch Context.